# Вывод новостей по категориям Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, php, views

Здравствуйте, уважаемые знатоки Друпала!

Не так давно, по мере свободного времени начал изучать Друпал. Задача примитивная - создать страницу со списком новостей, в сайдбаре вывести категории.
Что сделано:

1. Создал новый тип контента - News entry
2. Создал новый словарь в таксономии - Web development. Items - PHP, JS, HTML, MYSQL и т.д.
3. Добавил категорию к News entry
4. Установил модуль Views.
5. Создал с помощью Views новую страницу, которая выводит все News entry. URL - site.name/news
6. С помощью Views создал блок, который в сайд баре выводит категории.

Вопрос в следующем:

1. Как сделать чтоб url были вида - site.name/news/php/... когда нажимаешь на категорию. По умолчанию - http://site.name/taxonomy/term/11
2. Как вообще правильно реализовать тот функционал что я описал выше.
3. Если в таксономии на каждый item я вручную напишу news/php в качестве url, кажется что это будет не совсем правильно. Хотелось бы чтоб taxonomy term сам подхватывал news.
4. Когда я открываю пост либо категорию - News не является активным пунктом меню. Как исправить?

P.S.: Тема Aberdeen c drupal.org

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Модули `Path` и `Pathauto`, также не забудьте про `Transliteration` для транслита в урлах и `Global Redirect`, чтобы избежать дублей.
2. Теоритически всё правильно
3. Да, неправильно, с помощью правил в `Path` будет подхватываться в автомате.
4. Модуль `Сontext`, либо с помощью `jQuery`, но модулем проще.

Comment: Спасибо! С URL разобрался, все как надо работает. А вот с Context пока не получается. Не подскажите пошагово как правильно сделать подсветку меню если находимся в категории или в просмотре статьи?

Comment: К сожалению, не могу подсказать так как давно уже с этим модулем и с подобными задачами не сталкивался.
Попробуйте вот этот модуль (по описанию подходит) http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu_trails

Comment: ок, спасибо за помощь!